# GROUP BY with having clause and min function in sql

Tags: mysql

```
sharedid   property  shareduser  shareddatetime 
111        32        129         2015-02-02 13:30:44
117        33        129         2015-02-02 13:41:21
119        33        129         2015-02-02 13:40:44
```

In the above table I am showing the result what I got. Now I want my result like where shareduser should be 129 and where shareddatetime is minimum with group by on property column.
I have run the below query

```
SELECT * FROM sharing WHERE `shareduser` = 129 GROUP BY property HAVING min(shareddatetime)
```

result:

```
sharedid   property  shareduser  shareddatetime 
111        32        129         2015-02-02 13:30:44
117        33        129         2015-02-02 13:41:21
```

But the expected output is not coming with min().
I want result like

```
sharedid   property  shareduser  shareddatetime 
111        32        129         2015-02-02 13:30:44
119        33        129         2015-02-02 13:40:44
```

Comment: `MIN` doesn't do what you think it does, it merely selects the lowest value for the column in the grouped data - and in this instance, you're not actually selecting it; you'd need `SELECT MIN(shareddatetime), sharing.*` or similar. `HAVING MIN(shareddatetime)` basically states that there must be a `MIN(shareddatetime)` ... which of course there is.

Answer (score 1):

Your having clause is incorrect, check standard SQL syntax for that.
You can use a subquery for obtain the property with the minimun value.

```
  SELECT * FROM sharing WHERE `shareduser` = 129
  and   `shareddatetime` = ( select min( `shareddatetime` )
    from  sharing  s2
    where  s2.`shareduser` = sharing.`shareduser`
    and    s2.`property`   = sharing.`property` )
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22ee4a/3 (Using Kalid schema)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self join to get the desired results

```
select s.* 
from sharing s
join( select `property`, `shareduser`,min(shareddatetime) shareddatetime
     from sharing
     where `shareduser` = 129 
     group by `property`, `shareduser`
) s1
using(`property`, `shareduser`,shareddatetime)
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22ee4a/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s1.* FROM sharing s1 inner join
(select min(shareddatetime) minshareddatetime FROM sharing group by property) tmp
on s1.shareddatetime = tmp.minshareddatetime
where s1.shareduser = 129;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM sharing WHERE shareduser = 129 ORDER BY shareddatatime asc`
This should do it

and for the group by I actually forgot you can use:

`ORDER BY property asc, shareddatatime asc`

Comment: asc= lowest

desc=highest